# How can I make this code more optimized?

Tags: java, optimization

The objective is to make two methods :-

1. To find numbers that are k prime.

   ```
   countKprime(int k,long a,long b)
   ```

   k prime means numbers having k prime factors. eg: 4 -> 2 (2 and 2)
2. To find all the ways of using three numbers ( 1prime 3prime 7prime) to get 
   the given number

   ```
   puzzle(int s)
   ```

This is how I tried to do it :-

```
import java.util.*;
public class KPrimes {

public static long[] countKprimes(int k, long start, long end) {
    ArrayList<Long> list=new ArrayList<Long>();     
    for(;start<=end;start++)
    {
        if(k==fact(start))
        {
            list.add(start);
        }
    }
    return toArray(list);
}
public static long[] toArray(ArrayList<Long> l)
{
    long[] r=new long[l.size()];short x=0;
    for(long a:l)
    {
        r[x++]=a;
    }
    return r;
}
public static int fact(long x)
{
    long p=nextprime(1);
    int n=0;
    do
    {
        while(x%p==0&&x!=0)
        {
            n++;
            x/=p;
        }
            p=nextprime(p);
    }
    while(x>1);
    return n;
}
public static long nextprime(long s) {
    s++;
    for(;;s++)
    {
        int f=0;
        if(s%2!=0||s==2)
        {
            int t=(int)Math.sqrt(s);
        for(int x=2;x<=t;x++)
        {
            if(s%x==0){f++;break;}
        }
        if(f==0){break;}
        }
    }
    return s;
}
public static int puzzle(int x)
{
    long p1[]=countKprimes(1,0,x);
    long p3[]=countKprimes(3,0,x-p1[0]);
    long p7[]=countKprimes(7,0,x-p1[0]-p3[0]);

    int n=0;

    for(int a=0;a<p1.length;a++)
    {
        int x2=x;
        x2-=p1[a];
        for(int b=0;b<p3.length;b++)
        {
            x2-=p3[b];
            for(int c=0;c<p7.length;c++)
            {
                if(p7[c]==x2)
                {
                    n++;
                }
            }
            x2+=p3[b];
        }
    }
    return n;
}
}
```

I got the question from CodeWars but my code takes too much time.
I need help to optimize it, especially the last part.

Comment: This should probably better go to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Sirko Or codepuzzle

Comment: @P Joe : How big are the numbers going to be ? Could you use shorts ? Whats long b for ?

Comment: @user7185318   Numbers can be 3-digit at most, maybe. The return type must be 'long' for countKprimes. long a is the start(min) and long b is the end(max).

Comment: @P Joe : So the challenge is you have for example 9 and its 3*3*3, solved, or 16 =  2*2*4 ?

Comment: @user7185318 It is 9 =3*3*3 and 16=2*2*2*2

Comment: @P Joe : Ah, it has to split the numbers into their factors...